# Setting RavenDB ApiKey in NServiceBus 3.2.3

Tags: nservicebus, api-key, ravenhq

I am trying to set the RavenDB `DocumentStore.ApiKey` in NServiceBus 3.2.3.  According to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/fQape6ZFjLI/kcWBPCQqT00J), this is not able to be read directly from the connection string by the version of RavenDB used in NSB 3.2.3.

The `DocumentStore` instance in NSB is registered as an `IDocumentStore`, which means I cannot use a custom action like this as `IDocumentStore` does not expose `ApiKey`:

```
Configure.With()
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .RavenPersistence()
    .RunCustomAction(() => 
        Configure.Instance.Configurer
        .ConfigureProperty<IDocumentStore>(store => store.ApiKey, "my-api-key"));
```

There doesn't seem to be  overload of the `RavenPersistence` extension that allows me to supply an `IDocumentStore`.  Is there any way I can set the `ApiKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We internalize the Raven client so there is no way for you to set that property. The only work around that comes to mind is to use the core only version of nservicebus (that would make the code you mention in your question to work properly) The development version of NSB has been upgraded to Raven 960 so another option would be to upgrade to the CI version of NServiceBus (http://builds.nservicebus.com/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc)

Comment: Thanks Andreas.  CI it is then :)