# NServiceBus with RavenDB api-keys

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, nservicebus3

I am trying to setup NServiceBus 3.3.5 to use centerlized RavenDB instead of running RavenDB on every application server. I am able to use NServiceBus.Persistence with Windows username/password and it works. However, I would like to use APIKeys if possible.

Works:

```
<add name="NServiceBus.Persistence"
     connectionString="Url=http://DBServerName:8080;Database=DBName;User=Domain\RavenDBTestUser;Password=**********;" />
```

Doesn't work:

```
<add name="NServiceBus.Persistence"
     connectionString="Url = http://DBServerName:8080/; ApiKey = NServiceBusClients/SecretKey; Database = DBName" />
```

I get the following error (RavenDB returns 403) when starting the service ...

```
FATAL 06:32:23 Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Raven.Client.IDocumentStore)' on type 'RavenTimeoutPersistence'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 279
```

The user Domain\RavenDBTestUser and api-key have identical access in RavenDB. I have gone thru [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240353/setting-ravendb-apikey-in-nservicebus-3-2-3) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ravendb/fQape6ZFjLI/kcWBPCQqT00J) but those are from mid-last year and about version 3.2.3. Is it still the same in 3.3.5 or am I doing something wrong?

P.S. The connection string is copied-pasted from Raven Studio so there is no typo in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus v3.3.5 still uses RavenDb v1, unfortunately I can't find much doco about the use of APIKeys in Raven v1, the only thing I found is http://ravendb.net/docs/1.0/server/bundles/authentication

The link above states that you need the "Authentication Bundle", do you have this installed?

On the other hand, NServiceBus v4 uses RavenDB v2, and from reading [this page](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/authentication#oauth-authentication), it should be easy to set it up.
NServiceBus v4 beta has just been released, see http://nservicebus.com/

Comment: I am planning to upgrade to 4.0 already but I wasn't sure if it is not working because I did not setup something correctly or because it is not supposed to work. Those links are pretty clear that it wasn't supposed to work with 3.2.3. I will try 4.0 in next couple of days. Thanks for the answer. I will leave it open if someone else can confirm it either way.